# Error when trying to create site from site template

Tags: 2010, site-template

I have a strange issue when I try to create a site from site template.

This is a custom site template which I've created. When I try to create a site based on this site template I receive this error:

> Error loading and running event receiver
>   KWizCom.SharePoint.Features.SLFEFeature.SLFEEventHandler in
>   KWizCom.SharePoint.Features.SLFEFeature, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=30fb4ddbec95ff8f. Additional
>   information is below. Unable to load assembly group. The user assembly
>   group provider was unable to provide any user assemblies for the
>   specified assembly group

Any idea how I can solve this?

I tried to deactivate the solution but still without luck.

Comment: is there any web provisoned  event reciever running ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks Like assemblies from custom solution  KWizCom.SharePoint.Features.SLFEFeature are missing or not registered properly in test environment.
 Please ensure this custom solution is correctly deployed in test environment.

How you create the custom Template?